# Configuring Nginx to serve a UWSGI app from a location under a nodejs server block

Tags: nginx, node.js, uwsgi

I have a UWSGI Django API running which is configured like this in NGINX:

```
upstream django_api {                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    server 127.0.0.1:8088;                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}

server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    server_name api.domain.com;                                                                                                                                                                                            
    root /home/www/api/domain/;                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.domain.com-access.log;                                                                                                                                                                                      
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.domain.com-error.log;

   location / {                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     uwsgi_pass  django_api;                                                                                                                                                                                                               
     include     uwsgi_params;                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     uwsgi_read_timeout 600;                                                                                                                                                                                                               
     add_header Host $hostname;                                                                                                                                                                               
    } 
}
```

And a node app configured like this:

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    server_name app.domain.com;                                                                                                                                                                                 
    root /home/www/app/dist/;                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app.domain.com-access.log;                                                                                                                                                                           
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app.domain.com-error.log;                                                                                                                                                                             

    location / {                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        proxy_cache domain_zone;                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }
}
```

I want to serve the Django api from a sub path of my app (like app.domain.com/api/) as well as api.domain.com.

Normally I would think that I need a new location block under app.domain.com like this:

```
location /api/ {                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                                                                                                                                                                              
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;                                                                                                                                                                                        
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8088;                                                                                                                                                                                                            
}
```

But it doesn't work and I get a 500 error. I have tried many other configs with no luck. Can this be done?

Comment: Show the `uwsgi` log of a failed request. AFAIK, you have to modify your django source code as well if you want to serve it from something like `/api/`. Did you do this?

Comment: I guesss you should use `uwsgi_pass` too

Comment: @AlexeyTen I think your suggestion did the trick. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the `uwsgi_pass` did the trick apparently, thank you Alexy for the advice.

The new config is like this now:

```
location /api/ {
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8088;

    uwsgi_pass  django_api;
    include     uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
    add_header Host $hostname;
}
```